# Game Dev - Reply and Follow Player Move

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I have 2 actors.

1. Parent
2. Child

What I want to do is child always follow parent exactly same move.

See more clearly what I mean in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SoMLclPOPM

Look at the parent(blue bird) run and get their kids(yellow bird). All kids are always following their parent exactly same position.

What I'm thinking right now is make a big circular linked list of coordinate.

If player could has for example max 10 child and run in 60 FPS, then I need to create a single circular linked list with size 60*10 = 600.

Parent and all child could access it with their own counter.

So, every parent move would save it coordinate in circular linked list which would use by their kid.

What is the best approach and fastest solution to do this?

Comment: where is your code? Could you simplify and specify your question please?

Comment: Feels like it might be a [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).  Your "main" actor executes user commands, then you save the command in a queue or list.  Other actors read those same commands out of the queue and execute them, delayed slightly to make them "follow" the main actor.

Comment: Tim: I haven't coded yet. This approach just pop in my head, but I think it is not the best solution. 

@markspace: Yes, I found similar approach like yours. Some people said "Replay System". There are so many approach, one of them just like you said. I think I would try your solution. Thanks